# When to schedule next frame render from CARenderer?

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, core-animation

If I schedule next frame render performed with `CARenderer` to occur using a constant 1./60., everything is working fine. `-[CARenderer nextFrameTime]` method is supposed to provide a more fine-grained feedback on when the render should be happening.

Getting the media time for the next scheduled animated occurrence, or infinity in case there is nothing scheduled to occur, is a great solution to rendering even if nothing is happening.

However, now that the timer no longer fires (since I got infinity as the result), no animation at all occurs even upon user-initiated changes performed through event handlers. I have no idea how to get notified that a change has occurred in the layer tree and how to initiate the next render, even if it's unscheduled.

Observing `nextFrameTime` via KVO does not work (not that I expected it to). For my use case, hosting the layer in an `NSView` is not an option.

How would I know that a change has occurred in the layer tree (or on an animation in the layer tree), so I can trigger rendering?